# bash: how to print multiple arrays values

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting, array

I'm new to shell scripting and trying to figure out how to print 3 (or more) values of an array at once. Here's the word list I'm working with:

```
$ cat words.txt 
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
```

Here's the script I started:

```
$ cat test.sh

#!/bin/bash

arr=($(cat words.txt))

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
echo "$i" "$i" "$i"
done
```

Desired output:

> one two three
>
> four five six
>
> seven eight nine

If using a for loop isn't the best and most practical method for obtaining the desired output, I'm very open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

A crude way of doing it:
Use a counter variable that is incremented for each line in file. Every 3 iterations add a newline (`\n`).

```
!/bin/bash

counter=1

cat "words.txt" | while read i
do
        echo -n "$i "
        if [ `expr $counter % 3` -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo -en "\n"
        fi
        let counter=counter+1
done
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! How could I apply this to a curl script where I'm downloading multiple files at once? `$ curl -O one -O two -O three`

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with xargs. With `-n3` xargs will use 3 arguments at same time for the default `echo` command.

```
echo "${arr[@]} | xargs -n3
```